# Get music listens using FQL

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to get music.listens for a user and a user's friends using FQL.

Does anyone know what is the FQL query for getting music.listens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot currently query for Open Graph actions using FQL

You need to use the Graph API. You'll need the user_actions.music and/or friends_actions.music permissions, then you'll be able to GET:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/UID/music.listens?access_token=TOKEN
```

Answer (score 2):

it's possible to query via FQL in this style:

`/fql?q=SELECT id FROM open_graph_action WHERE id = XXXXX`

or:

`fql?q=SELECT id, objects, tags, type, app_id, place, end_time, publish_time FROM open_graph_action WHERE id = XXXXX`

That's all I know so far, no docs yet.